# Let f(x) be a derivable function, $f'(x) > f(x)$ and $f(0) = 0$. What can be said about the sign of $f(x)?$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f(x)$ be a derivable function, $f'(x) > f(x)$ and $f(0) = 0$. Then
>
> (A) $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$
>
> (B) $f(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$
>
> (C) no sign of $f(x)$ can be ascertained
>
> (D) $f(x)$ is a constant function

Since the mean value theorems are not applicable where do I start?
I tried this:

$f'(x)>f(x)$

$=> f'(0)>f(0)$

$=> f'(0)>0$

Comment: Yes, so your first result is that at $x=0$, the function is an increasing function. Can the derivative ever become negative?

Comment: @MattiP.  A parabola passing through (0,0) with the vertex in the third quadrant and concave upward?

Comment: Who says that it's a parabola?

Comment: @MattiP. no one does, but I don't know what the curve is, so how can I determine whether the derivative is negative from the result that I got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt:

Let $x >0$;

You got $f'(0)>0$.

$\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$;

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)/x= f'(0)>0$.

For $x_0$ small enough $f(x_0)/x_0 >0$, i.e. $f(x_0)>0$.

Assume there is an $x_1 >x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)>f(x_1)$.

The continuos function $f$ attains its maximum on $[x_0,x_1]$.

$f'(x_0) \le 0$, if maximum occurs at $x_0$, or $f'(t)=0$ if maximum occurs at $x_0<t <x_1$.

Then $f(x_0) >0$ and $f'(x_0) \le 0$, or $f(t)>0$ and $f'(t)=0$, a contradiction.

Hence solution $A$.

Comment: I can't understand "$f'(x_0) \le 0$, if maximum occurs at $x_0$".

Comment: Tapi.Maximum could occur at $x_0$, then you could have $f'(x_0) <0$.Example: Let $x_0 =0$; Interval: $[0,1]$: $f(0)=3$; $f(1)=0$, joined by a line.$f(x)=-3(x-1)$; $f'(0)=-3$, negative, ok?

Comment: Yes, okay. So basically we're assuming that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function by setting $x_1 >x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)>f(x_1)$ and proving that it is not by contradiction.

Comment: Yes!Assume $f$ is decreasing somewhere. Chose the maximum to make sure we still have $f>0$. Since $\max \ge f(x_0)$ in the interval.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x\ge 0$,then
$$f'(x)>f(x) \implies e^{-x} f'(x) > e^{-x} f(x) \implies \frac{d}{dx} [e^{-x}f(x)]>0.$$ This means that $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$ is an increasing function. So $g(x) \ge g(0), for x \ge 0$. Then we have $g(x)>0 \implies f(x) \ge 0 ~\text{for}~ x\ge 0.$

Comment: Are there any particular cases where you know that you have to multiply $e^{-x}$ or such expressions to deduce something? Or is it just based on observation?

Comment: If you have $f(x)-f'(x)$ multiply by $e^{-x}$ since $(e^{-x}f(x))' = e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))$; if you have $f(x)+f'(x)$ multiply by $e^x$ since $(e^{x}f(x))' = e^{x}(f'(x)+f(x))$.

Comment: @martycohen I got it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is A.

Let $F(x)=f(x)\cdot e^{-x}$ ,so
$$F(0)=0,\,F’(x)=\left(f’(x)-f(x)\right)\cdot e^{-x}>0$$
So
$$\forall x>0,F(x)>0,f(x)=F(x)\cdot e^x>0$$

So why I multiply $e^{-x}$?It just need some ways to solve it. I want to find a helpful function $F(x)=f(x)g(x)$ to use $f’(x)>f(x)$, we know $F’(x)=f’(x)g(x)+f(x)g’(x)$, so if $g’(x)=-g(x)$, we can use it.

Which $g(x)$ is $g’(x)=-g(x)$ ？ 
$e^{-x}$!

Comment: Are there any particular cases where you know that you have to multiply $e^{−x}$ or such expressions to deduce something? Or is it just based on observation?

Comment: @Tapi maybe observe.

Comment: @Tapi (for my edit)